# Compiling nginx using CLion (via CMake)

Tags: nginx, makefile, cmake, clion

I'm trying to compile [nginx 1.9.5](https://github.com/nginx/nginx/tree/release-1.9.5) via CLion for debugging purposes.

Because CLion doesn't currently support vanilla Makefiles/Autoconf I ran the autoconf `auto/configure` script to generate a valid Makefile, opened the project in CLion, then made a very simple `CMakeLists.txt` to delegate the CLion build to the autoconf generated `Makefile` (as advised by [Using local makefile for CLion instead of CMake](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26918459/using-local-makefile-for-clion-instead-of-cmake)).

Unfortunately, my simple `CMakeLists.txt` seems to have a flaw, as when I reload and run CLion's build command, CMake seems to generate yet a new Makefile and run this empty Make task instead of running the one in ${nginx_SOURCE_DIR}.

How can I change the CMakeLists.txt file below to delegate to the nginx Makefile instead of regenerating a new one?

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.4)
project(nginx)

add_custom_target(nginx ALL COMMAND make -C ${nginx_SOURCE_DIR} CLION_EXE_DIR=${PROJECT_BINARY_DIR})
```